# Slim 3 upload image to server path

Tags: php, slim-3

Hi  im new in slim 3 framework (Api for mobile) i would like to know how to upload an image to a server, e seacrh for examples didnt find much, this is the code i have but it does not work.Any help would be great thanks.

```
  $app->post('/photo', function ($request, $response) use ($app) {

   $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    if (empty($files['newfile'])) {
       throw new Exception('Expected a newfile');
    }

   $newfile = $files['newfile'];


   if ($newfile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   $uploadFileName = $newfile->getClientFilename();
   $newfile->moveTo("../photos/");
   }

 });
```

The error it gives me

```
 <h1>Slim Application Error</h1>
    <p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p>
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <div>
        <strong>Type:</strong> Error
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>Message:</strong> Call to a member function getError() on null
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>File:</strong> /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/public/index.php
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>Line:</strong> 155
    </div>
    <h2>Trace</h2>
```

```
#0 [internal function]: Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#1 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)

#2 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(344): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)

#3 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))

#4 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(316): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))

#5 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(476): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))

#6 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))

#7 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(370): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))

#8 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(295): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))

#9 /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/public/index.php(161): Slim\App->run()

#10 {main}
```

Comment: Could you expand on what _"but it does not work"_ means? Also, maybe post the complete code you've tried? (The `// do something with $newfile` suggests that you've removed your attempt?)

Comment: Check the error log for the actual error message. You could also tell Slim to show you the actual error message with the setting: `'displayErrorDetails' => true`, which is preferred while you develop.

Comment: i fallow this example -> https://akrabat.com/psr-7-file-uploads-in-slim-3/

Comment: We still need to see the actual error message. Please turn on `displayErrorDetails` as suggested above and try again. Btw, did you change `/path/to/` in the `$newfile->moveTo("/path/to/$uploadFileName")` call? That needs to be set to an absolute path on your server, where your PHP code has write permission.

Comment: ok i updated the question, buts there is any example should i fallow?

Comment: How do you test using Postman? The example you're following depends on a file being sent from a form (or at least with the type `multipart/form-data` and with a file input field named `newfile`). If it works through a form (from the example link), then you're code works and it's just your Postman call that's incorrect (which I can't help you with).

Comment: thanks , it give me a diferent erro  now Details

Type: RuntimeException
Message: Error moving uploaded file soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg to http://xxxx/api_pricegram/photos/
 File: /home/bitstudi/public_html/api_pricegram/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/UploadedFile.php
Line: 236

Comment: Then check that you have permission to write to that folder.

Comment: yess i do have permission

Comment: Can we see your form please?

Comment: Also here is a slim example https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/uploading-files.html. From what I can tell you are using some slim 2 styles the use($app)

Comment: thanks guys i solved much thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved like this

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Slim\Http\UploadedFile;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App([
'settings' => [
  'displayErrorDetails' => true
]
  ]);



$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['upload_directory'] ='../photos/';

$app->post('/photo', function (Request $request, Response  $response) use ($app) {

$directory = $this->get('upload_directory');

$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

$uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['picture'];
  if($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);
    $response->write('uploaded ' . $filename . '<br/>');
 }

 });


 function moveUploadedFile($directory, UploadedFile $uploadedFile){
 $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename(), 
 PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $basename = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
 $filename = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $basename, $extension);
 $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);

return $filename;
}


$app->run();
```